# What does the word "manoeuvring" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a space action game:

> The firing is automatic, so that you can focus on manoeuvring the
>   soldier between risky cover positions, dodging incoming grenades and
>   avoiding sniper beams.

Does the word **manoeuvring** simply mean **moving** here?

I know the lexical meanings of the word ["maneuver"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maneuver), but am not sure which of them fits here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This verb is a synonym of "to move" but with a  little connotation (to move in a careful way).

See the entry from [Oxford Dictionary:](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/maneuver)

"***Move skillfully or carefully.***

no object

‘the truck was unable to maneuver comfortably in the narrow street’"